# Update and find-smallest-absolute-value operations on a tree

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, trees, binary-trees

I have a balanced binary tree that stores a number in each node, initially zero.  I want to build a data structure that will support the following two operations:

1. Given a vertex $v$ in the tree and a real value $w$, add $w$ to all nodes in the subtree under $v$.
2. Given a vertex $v$ in the tree, find the smallest absolute value associated with any node in the subtree of $v$.

The shape of the tree is static and remains unchanged. No new vertices can be added.  We don't need to support any other operations (e.g., insert a node, delete a node, lookup the value in a node).

I want the running time of both operations to be $O(\lg n)$, where $n$ is the number of nodes in the tree.  How can I do that?  Recursively visiting all nodes in the subtree would be too slow, as it would take $O(n)$ time.

Comment: Nice question! What are your thoughts on it?

Comment: Are there any constraints on the space usage of the data structure?  What's the source of the problem?  Do you have a reason to believe both operations can be supported in $O(\lg n)$ time?  Are you OK with  an amortized running time?

Comment: no space restrictions, fine with amortized running time.
Normal min or max of subtree can be supported in $O(\lg n)$, so I believe this might also be possible in same time.